# Derrick Henry forward fumble into end zone

Tags: rules, nfl

During Sunday's game (November 27, 2022, 2022 Week 12) between the Cincinnati and Tennessee, Derrick Henry fumbled the ball forward where it was recovered in the end zone by fellow Titan Treylon Burks and Tennessee was awarded a touchdown. (This happened with 11:18 to go in the second quarter and can be seen at about 3 minutes into this [official highlight video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VtE1tju622I)).

Why was this ruled a touchdown? I thought forward fumbles into the end zone were "banned" after the [Holy Roller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holy_Roller_(American_football)) (see also this question of [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Are-NFL-players-allowed-to-purposely-fumble-the-ball-forward-in-order-to-give-it-to-a-teammate)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [2022 NFL Rulebook](https://operations.nfl.com/media/5kvgzyss/2022-nfl-rulebook-final.pdf), this is covered by Rule 8, Section 7, Article 3, item 1, with some other bits supporting.

> 8-7-3
>
> **Item 1. Recovery and Advance.**  Any player of either team may recover or
> catch a fumble and advance, either before or after the ball strikes
> the ground.
>
> **Exceptions:**
>
> (a) Fourth-down fumble. See 8-7-5 below.
>
> (b) Fumble after two-minute
> warning. See 8-7-6 below.

As this was not on fourth down, after the two minute warning, or during a try (which is mentioned in 8-7-6), no exceptions apply and the fumble may be recovered and advanced by any player.